# "Фотографія" чи "світлина"?

Tags: вибір-слова, синоніми

Все частіше зустрічаю вживання слова **світлина** в значенні [фотографія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F).

> Фотографією (або світлиною) називають також результат фотографічного процесу — зображення, електронне або отримане на певному матеріалі, здебільшого на цупкому папері.

А [онлайн коректор](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/), наприклад, зазначає, що вживання слова "світлина" є більш вдалим. Чи є між словами "фотографія" та "світлина" суттєві відмінності, чи особливості вживання?

Comment: а якщо фото цифрове? також світлина доречно?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Думаю, що це відродження старого західноукраїнського слова "світлина". На відміну від неологізмів, воно вже має досить довгу історію існування.

Словник української мови (СУМ-11):

> [СВІТЛИ́НА](http://sum.in.ua/s/svitlyna), и, жін.
>   1. зах., заст. Фотографія. *Багато з тих листів, світлин і рукописів моїх і Франка знищила воєнна хуртовина (Уляна Кравченко, Вибр., 1958, 424).*

Крім того, світлину у значенні "фотографічний знімок" наводять [словники 20-30-х років](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on):

**Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр.**

> **Зас’ёмка** –
>   3) (снимок) зняток; (-тку), зні́мок (-мку), **світли́на**, фотогра́фія.
>   Недоде́рживать, недодержа́ть – недоде́ржувати, недоде́ржати, недотри́мувати, недотри́мати що, чого́.
>
> - Недоде́ржанный – недоде́ржаний, недотри́маний. 
>     • -ный снимок, фотогр. – недоде́ржаний зні́мок (зня́ток), -на **світли́на**.

**Російсько-український словник технічної термінології 1928р.**

> Фотография – фотогра́фія;
>
> - ф., снимок – ф., **світли́на**;
>     • ф. мгновенная – ф., **с.** миттьова́;
>     • ф. стереоскопическая – ф.-стереоскопі́чна;
>     • ф. трехцветная – ф., **с.** трикольоро́ва.

**Російсько-український словник ділової мови 1930р.**

> **Снимок (фотографический)** – світлина.
>   Фотография –
>   1) (заведение) – фотогра́фія, **світлярня**;
>   2) (фотографическое изображение) – **світлина**; снимать -фию – фотографува́ти, **світлити**.

Тобто в усіх словниках "світлина" означає "фотознімок". Видно, що у словниках 20-30-х років обидва слова є повними синонімами.

Додам, що на фотографічних форумах мені зустрічалися дещо ліричні тексти, де фотографи порівнювали своє мистецтво із живописом, але замість фарб у цьому мистецтві використовується світло. З цієї точки зору "світлина" підкреслює саме цей аспект фотографії і, можливо, через це людям подобається слово, що походить від слова "світло".

Answer (score 6):

Слово "фотографія" входить до академічного тлумачного Словника української мови (1970—1980), отже, є припустимим для вживання:

> **[ФОТОГРА́ФІЯ, ї, жін.](http://sum.in.ua/s/fotoghrafija)** 1. Спосіб одержання зображення кого-, чого-небудь на світлочутливому матеріалі за допомогою спеціального оптичного апарата. За два тижні по тому запрохав я ще одного аматора фотографії, поклав на бричку апарат І гайда до гуцулії в гостину *(Михайло Коцюбинський, I, 1955, 255)*;

Окрім того, слово "фотографія" скорочується до коротшого "[фото](http://sum.in.ua/s/foto)" без втрати сенсу, що може додатково сприяти вживанню цієї його форми.

Наприклад, саме слова "фотографія" і "фото" вживаються у назві сервісу "Google Фото: упорядковані фотографії, які легше знайти".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наразі цей допис виглядає як субʼєктивна точка зору автора, і тому не відповідає критеріям якості. Його або варто розширити до повноцінної відповіді, з посиланнями на те, хто і як використовує це слово таким чином, або перетворити на коментар (коли ваша репутація на сайті дозволить робити коментарі). Окрім того, за вашою ж логікою, слово «фотографія» є довшим (і тому — гіршим), ніж слово «світлина». Також, перегляньте [faq] і озирніться навколо, щоб дізнатися, як інші користувачі оформлюють свої відповіді.

Comment: Дякую за зауваження @bytebuster. Розширив текст до повноцінної відповіді (сподіваюся).

Answer (score 2):

Світлина - українське слово українського походження, від українського - світло. Фотографія - українське слово іноземного походження, від грецького φωτός(світло) і латинского γραφική(зображення, малюнок, креслення...). Я б рекомендувала використовувати слово "світлина", бо воно більш зрозуміле для нашого народу, більш характерне для корінної мови. Просто стало незвичним, через тотальну русифікацію більшість українських слів, нажаль, стали незвичними для українців, це наслідок колонізації.

Comment: Я ще розумію, що можна продовжити цей ряд по типу фотокопія - світловідбиток, фоторепортаж - світлозвітність, фотосток - світлокомора, фотограф - світляр тощо. Але тоді як відрізнити фотосалон і фотокамера? Це теж перекладається як світлокімната. Фотокелія?

Answer (score 0):

Ніколи не чув слова світлина то того, як його почали використовувати на телебаченні. Тому, сказати, що воно більш зрозуміле аж ніяк не можна.
До того ж, в українській літературі слово "[фотографія](https://yak-pyshetsya.com/search/%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D1%8F)" зустрічається набагато частіше ніж "[світлина](https://yak-pyshetsya.com/search/%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0)"

Comment: Це жахлива відповідь, оскільки заснована на 100% на власному суб'єктивному досвіді, що категорично не схвалюється на SE ресурсах. Нікого не цікавить і нікому не потрібна ваша суб'єктивна думка.

Comment: А для кого, цікаво, я додав посилання? Пошук у ГРАКу підтверджує мої слова: "світлина" - 28,349, "фотографія" - 88,650. А от ваше повідомлення взагалі не має ніякого сенсу.

Comment: Ваша відповідь цілковито є вираженням власної суб'єктивної думки. `Ніколи не чув слова світлина то того, як його почали використовувати на телебаченні. ` - нікого не цікавить і нікому не потрібна ваша повністю суб'єктивна думка. Хто сказав яке слово є більш чи менш зрозумілим? Ах, в джерелах показано, що слово *фотографія* зустрічається частіше? Так чому ви не написали в цій відповіді, що це показано в джерелах? Інакше, така відповідь є суб'єктивною. Читайте [вікі про те як писати правильні відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)!