# Різниця між "опанування" і "оволодіння"

Tags: різниця-між-словами, синоніми

Свого часу намагався закликати користувачів деякого форуму до "Опанування української мови" шляхом переходу на неї замість російської.
Мене виправили, сказавши, що більш доречним варіантом було б вживання слова "Оволодіння".

Чи є принципова різниця між цими двома словами? Чи пов'язана вона якось зі стадією завершеності цього самого оволодіння чимось?

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Чи дивилися ви у словники у спробі самостійно відповісти на запитання? Якщо так, то варто уточнювати, чим са́ме не сподобалися відповіді, що там є. Ось, як інші користувачі оформлюють подібні запитання: [один](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1157/), [два](http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1068/)

Comment: Дякую, саме тому і запитав, що звернення до словників не дало мені розуміння різниці цих слів в даному контексті, де мене спробували виправити. В майбутньому обов'язково використовуватиму запропонований вами формат питання.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У Словнику української мови:

[Оволодівати](http://sum.in.ua/s/ovolodivaty) має потрібне значення під номером 3, та ще й з приміткою "переносне значення":

> 3. чим, перен. **Твердо засвоювати що-небудь.** *Член партії повинен: ..оволодівати марксистсько-ленінською теорією, підвищувати свій ідейний рівень, сприяти формуванню і вихованню людини комуністичного суспільства (Статут КПРС, 1971, 9); Чудово оволодівши мовою, він з захопленням прочитав поему «Садді Іскендерій» великого Навої (Іван Ле, Міжгір'я, 1953, 28);*
>    //  **Набувати ґрунтовних знань, умінь, навичок і т. ін. в чому-небудь.** *Він [лікар] день у день провадив навчання з своїми санітарами й санінструкторами, домагаючись, щоб вони досконало оволоділи професією рятівників людського життя в бою (Василь Кучер, Голод, 1961, 66).*

А у слова [опановувати](http://sum.in.ua/s/opanovuvaty) - це перше значення:

> ОПАНОВУВАТИ, ую, уєш, недок., ОПАНУВАТИ, ую, уєш, док., перех. і рідко неперех.
>
> 1. **Ґрунтовно засвоювати щось, оволодівати чим-небудь.** *Максим опановував складні вправи на натягнутому канаті, жонглював (Дмитро Ткач, Арена, 1960, 140); Кмітливий і працьовитий Микола Снігур швидко опанував ковальську справу (Анатолій Шиян, Гроза.., 1956, 452); День за днем і вона потроху опанувала тією премудрістю [писати] (Валентин Речмедін, Весняні грози, 1961, 102);*
>    //  **Навчатися користуватися чим-небудь.** *В обстановці напруженої боротьби Щорс знаходив час провадити навчання з партизанами, вчив їх опановувати зброю, воєнну тактику (Семен Скляренко, Легендарний начдив, 1957, 27); З часом люди набралися більше розуму, опанували вогонь, навчилися з кременя робити оружжя (Іван Франко, IV, 1950, 117);*
>    //  перев. док., рідко. **Зрозуміти зміст, значення чого-небудь.** Грудницький ще не зовсім опанував цю звістку і в першу мить хотів навіть сміятися з неї (Іван Ле, Вибр., 1938, 171).

Отже "опановувати" застосовується в першу чергу для знань, а "оволодівати" для "брати силою" (перше значення) або "бути під владою почуттів" (друге значення).

Але обидва слова можуть використовуватися у смислі "опанування мови" чи "оволодіння мовою".